# C# Stream Reader adding \n to XML

Tags: c#, xml, streamreader, geocode

I use the StreamReader class to obtain XML for my GeoCoding process from Google.

```
StreamReader srGeoCode = new StreamReader(WebRequest.Create(Url).GetResponse().GetResponseStream());
String GeoCodeXml = srGeoCode.ReadToEnd();
XmlDocument XmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
GeoCode oGeoCode = new GeoCode();
XmlDoc.Load(GeoCodeXml);
```

I get XML back but it adds \n and other extras to the XML

```
<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\" ?>\n<kml xmlns=\"http://earth.google.com/kml/2.0\"><Response>\n  <name>
```

I have the same code in VB and it does not do this.  I can successfully GeoCode my information using the VB version of this console app.

Is there a reason the C# version adds this extra data to the XML that I retrieve back?  I am trying my best to convert everything over to C#.  I enjoy coding in it over VB.

Here is the VB Code:

```
    Dim wreqGeoCode As WebRequest = WebRequest.Create(strURL)
    Dim wresGeoCode As WebResponse = wreqGeoCode.GetResponse
    Dim srGeoCode As New StreamReader(wresGeoCode.GetResponseStream())
    Dim strXML As String = srGeoCode.ReadToEnd()
    Dim xmlDoc As New XmlDocument
    xmlDoc.LoadXml(strXML)
```

Comment: can you post the VB code as well?

Comment: Dim wreqGeoCode As WebRequest = WebRequest.Create(strURL)
        Dim wresGeoCode As WebResponse = wreqGeoCode.GetResponse
        Dim srGeoCode As New StreamReader(wresGeoCode.GetResponseStream())
        Dim strXML As String = srGeoCode.ReadToEnd()
        Dim xmlDoc As New XmlDocument

xmlDoc.LoadXml(strXML)

This was before I realized that I could combine the WebRequest call.  I also tried the C# way without combining the WebRequest.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need XmlDoc.LoadXml if you're going to load a string. Load loads from a file.

---

BTW, the alternative is also more efficient. You can load the document directly from the stream:

```
WebRequest webRequest = WebRequest.Create(Url);
using (WebResponse webResponse = webRequest.GetResponse())
{
    using (Stream responseStream = webResponse.GetResponseStream())
    {
        XmlDocument XmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
        GeoCode oGeoCode = new GeoCode();
        XmlDoc.Load(responseStream);
    }
}
```

The `using` statements ensure that the `WebResponse` and `Stream` get cleaned up, even if an exception is thrown.

Comment: +1, Yep, definitely this one, his VB version uses LoadXml and it works. His C# one uses Load and it doesn't.

Comment: Thank you.  I thought I copied that over from the VB one but it looks like I didn't.

Always nice to have a second pair of eyes look at your code.

Comment: Thanks!  I will look into changing the code to be more efficient.  On a side note, we have the same last name - lol

Answer (score 1):

y not just do

```
   GeoCodeXml=GeoCodeXml.Replace("\n","");
```

if it is truly returning the \n as mentioned here.

Comment: I can probably do that, was just trying to see why it's doing it.